Imitating `emacs /path/to/folder/` behavior with emacs client for project configuration file recognition
To save some time and flashing white screen at startup, I use the emacs daemon and launch a emacs client. However, I have the following project-based workflow that seems to require that I use the non-client version of emacs (or an annoying workaround).
This project-based workflow involves opening the project "root folder" (e.g. x25519-proof) that contains a easycrypt.project file which tells the easycrypt executable which folders belong to said project and some other general configuration options. Easycrypt is (basically) a Coq-like language for proving various interesting cryptographic "things".
For example, to recursively add the folder /path/to/x25519-proof/src/ and its subfolders to the project, the easycrypt.project file would look like so:
[general]
timeout = 30

rdirs = src

The easycrypt executable only locates this file if I open the non-client emacs from the terminal inside the project folder, i.e. running emacs /path/to/x25519-proof.  With the emacs client, even if I use dired to access the project folder and opening a file from there, easycrypt will not find the easycrypt.project file.
The only workaround I can find is placing a file named .dir-locals.el inside every single folder and subfolder in the project which leverages certain features of the proof general extension:
((easycrypt-mode .
  ((eval .
    (cl-flet ((pre (s) (concat (locate-dominating-file buffer-file-name ".dir-locals.el") s)))
      (setq easycrypt-load-path `(,(pre ".")))
      (setq easycrypt-prog-args  `("-emacs", "-pp-width", "150",
                  "-R", (pre "../src")))))))) -- relative path(s) to base folder
                  

For larger projects, this is not reasonable or feasible to do. Hence, my questions are:
How can I imitate the behavior of emacs /path/to/folder/ with the emacs client?
Related question that I found but I can't seem to apply it to my problem: How to open a folder as project in emacs?

A top level .dir-locals.el applies to a directory and all its subdirectories (although you can exclude subdirectories - see the manual). You only need one .dir-locals.el

"...easycrypt will not find the easycrypt.project file." - this sounds like a problem with easycrypt-mode. Have you tried asking them?

Only one question per post, please.

@NickD Then maybe I'll try one .dir-locals.el - the example project I looked at with .dir-locals.el had it in every folder. I should've looked at the manual, thanks :)
